# Computer Studdering When Transferring Over Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, performance, file-transfer

This is a really weird problem that I've never even seen before.

When I copy to or from my server share, my computer studders terribly and the data transfers very slowly at only around 12MB/s.  By studdering I mean the mouse skips around and all my applications respond very slowly; as soon as I cancel the transfer it resolves immediately.  I looked at Task Manager and the CPU is only at ~35% with plenty of RAM free.

This only started semi-recently; before, I had no problems and the transfer speed maxed out the gigabit connection.

I have two hard drives in my computer.  When I try transferring files between drives it's fine, but when I copy from the share to either drive or to it from either drive, I get studdering.

I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?  Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Network connection is gigabit.  Server specs are more than adequate to handle file sharing.  Dual core something or rather, 4gigs of RAM, and runs Debian (Lenny).  I don't think the problem is with the file server since it makes *my* computer studder.

Comment: what are the specs of the server share system?

Comment: 12 MB\s is 96Mbps, so that sounds pretty speedy for a 100Mbps FastEthernet link (I'm assuming that's what your connection is)

Comment: @joeqwerty no, it's gigabit.  before, i was transferring at ~115MB/s.  raided drives makes the transfer much faster.

Comment: Have you tried updating or even rolling back your network card drivers?